# Why won't the scroll bar go up when I use this javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, window

so I have this javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0 && !document.contains(document.getElementById('toTop'))) {
        var top = '<div id="toTop" onclick="tTop()"></div>';
        $('body').append(top);
    }
});
function tTop() {
    $('html,body').scrollTop(0);
}
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if (document.contains(document.getElementById('toTop')) && $(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
        $('div').remove('#toTop');
    }
});
```

It works just fine if the page is loaded while the scroll bar is at the top; however when I refresh the page while the scroll bar is at the bottom, the page will still scroll up, but the scroll stays at the bottom. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: You realise that every time that you scroll that `top` will be appended to your page...

Comment: Yeah, I fixed that literally seconds after I asked this hahaha, I'll update the code now.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working in the end?

Answer (score 1):

> when I refresh the page while the scroll bar is at the bottom, the
>   page will still scroll up, but the scroll stays at the bottom

Maybe I'm misreading this, but are you concerned that the buttons are staying at the bottom of the page? Or `$(window).scrollTop()` is set to 0 after you click the button, after a page refresh?

Regardless, I would separate the scroll callback to another method, checking if the element exists (I used a button for an example instead of a div)

```
function scrollCallback() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
        if ($('body').has('#toTop').length == false) {
            var top = '<input type="button" id="toTop" onclick="tTop();" value="top" />';
            $('body').append(top);
        }
    } 
    else {
        // Removes the button if the scroll is at the top of the page.
        $('body #toTop').remove();
    }
}
```

Then on your page load, call the scrollCallback, and set your scroll to also use the scroll back:

```
$(function() {
    // Execute it when you load the page.
    scrollCallback();       
    $(window).scroll(scrollCallback);
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the second half of your answers is saying but that sounds more like what I'm looking for.  However, I have no problem removing the button, I was just about to update the code anyway, I'll be sure to try the second half of this though. Thank you.

Comment: The first code block adds a check to see if the button exists on the web page. It also removes it with the same function/binding. I noticed that you're binding `$(window).scroll(` twice which could be part of the issue. The second/last code block runs the function once after the page is loaded, checking where the scroll position if anything needs to be done (adding or removing the button), then it binds the scroll event to the call back (which you were already doing).

Comment: Well, I can add and remove the button just fine now, but it's just the scroll bar won't go up with the page, and this only happens if I refresh the page with the scroll bar already at the bottom.

Comment: I'm able to use my code in IE(10)/Chrome(28)/Firefox(22). The code you have in the question works in chrome/firefox (after refresh too), but doesn't at all in IE (document.contains doesn't work). Is your javascript in a document ready function (Ex: `$(function() {`)?

Comment: It is not in a document ready function, would that fix it you think?

Comment: It's possible that the $(window) portion is being loaded before the page is fully loaded/jQuery itself is loaded. If you were to do this, you will need to leave the `tTop()` function outside of the page load.

Comment: oh tTop() is out, just then append and remove functions are in the $(window)